# VLC speed play in Android app

Tags: video, media-player, vlc

In VLC player there is a "faster" and "slower" button that makes the video go faster or slower so that if you need to learn something (for example a guitar solo) you can slow it down a bit or if someone is talking too slow in a documentary you can speed it up a bit.

Does anyone know any Android app that does the same? I have a couple of documentaries that I need to speed up on my tablet and it's driving me nuts that I cant do it.

I have tried these apps so far:

- VLC (neon)
  [UPDATE: VLC does support playback speed adjustment by now.  (See
  answer below.)]
- MX player
- Poweramp
- *and a couple others*

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

[**VLC for Android**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc) supports playback speed regulation up to 4.0x, with audio pitch adjustment (optional).

The setting is under `⋮` (<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub> *Advanced Options*).
[image]
<sub>Image source: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Android/#Video_playback_interface</sub>

Answer (score 2):

When you play an audio file in vlc tap the track name at the bottom to bring up the playlist. In the upper right tap the dots then the image of a man running. This changes playback speed. In settings you can check a box that says "remember playback speed" so that you won't have to do this again next time